# Advantages of using Spark with Cassandra

Tags: database, hadoop, apache-spark, cassandra, bigdata

I have seen that the combination of using Spark with Cassandra is relatively popular.

I know that Cassandra is a BigData solution that provides reliability over consistency, therefore fits for real time systems. It also provides an SQL-like syntax for queries, but under the hood manages its data very differently than a normal DB.

Hadoop on the other hand provides consistency over reliability, therefore fits for analytics systems. Its interface is MapReduce, which is quite slow and too low level for nowadays. So this is where Sparks comes in. Sparks uses Hadoop's HDFS and replaces the old MapReduce with better architecture that takes more advantage of memory rather than hard disk, and exposes better interfaces such as RDD and dataframes.

So my question is:
Why would I want to use Spark combined with Cassandra? What are the advantages of that? Why not to use just one of them?

As far as I understand, Cassandra would just replace the HDFS, so I'd have reliability over consistency, and I'd also have to use RDD/dataframes instead of CQL, and spark would generate CQL under the hood, which gives me fewer control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS is a "file system", hadoop sitting on top of it.

There are also many database engines that run on top of hadoop and hdfs, like hbase, hive etc and utilizing it's distributed architecture.

You don't have to run spark on hadoop, you can run it independently.

CQL of Cassandra is very, very basic. You have basic aggregation functions added in latest versions, but Cassandra wasn't designed for analytical workloads, and probably you will both struggle to run analytical queries and will "kill" your cluster performance.

You can't compare HDFS and Cassandra, like you can't compare ntfs and mysql. Cassandra is designed for heavy workloads and easy scalabilty based on Dynamo (AWS) and BigTable(Google) concepts and can handle very high number of requests per second. There's alternatives, running on hadoop like HBase, and Cassandra wins in every benchmark i've seen (but don't believe benchmarks, always test it with your data and for your use case).

So what Spark is trying to solve there, is executing analytical queries on top of data that sitting in Cassandra. Using Spark, you can take data from many sources (RDBMS, files, hadoop etc.) and execute analytical queries versus that data.

Also, this

> reliability over consistency, therefore fits for real time systems

is so wrong. There are many real time systems that need consistency (not eventual), serialization, transactions etc which Cassandra can't provide...

Answer (score 3):

Spark is a data processing framework. You are going to **process** your data with Spark.

Cassandra is a DBMS. You are going to **store** your data in Cassandra.

It is true that you can process data in Cassandra with CQL, and if you can get away with CQL, you probably don't need Spark. However, in general Spark is a way more powerful tool. In practice a lot of people use Spark to receive data from an external source, process it and store already processed data in Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is NoSQL database and it is very limited in functionality for analytics. 
For instance, CQL supports aggregation within single partition and there are no table joins. 
Spark is streaming processing engine, it could use data from HDFS or from database. So if you want to do deep analysis of data among the whole dataset, you have to use Spark for it.
You can read more about Cassandra and Big Data [here](http://www.issart.com/blog/can-use-cassandra-big-data-world/)